# Can't mount CIFS through fstab

Tags: networking, mount, fstab, cifs

Trying to mount a CIFS share (from Freenas) at boot, but I can't seem to get it to work.

```
//freenas/mast/ /media/plexshare cifs guest,uid=1000 iocharset=utf8 0 0
```

I've tried using an IP rather than 'freenas' but that doesn't help

What's weird is that this worked twice, then on the third reboot, stopped working, and now won't mount with

```
sudo mount -a
```

It just returns :

```
mount: /etc/fstab: parse error: ignore entry at line 13
```

I can access the share perfectly when browsing the network through the file manager. The path when accessing it that way is: smb://freenas.local/mast/ I've also tried adding the .local to the line in fstab, but again to no avail.

Answer (score 3):

I see an issue but it may just be a misprint ..

the line should be :

```
//freenas/mast/ /media/plexshare cifs guest,uid=1000,iocharset=utf8 0 0
```

you have a space after uid and iocharset and it should be a comma

As you mentioned you are getting an error about only being able to mount as root. I also suggested trying

```
//freenas/mast/ /media/plexshare cifs defaults 0 0
```

If that doesn't help I can tell you the way I was able to get a network share drive to automount.

first you need to create a file in your users home directory

open terminal ... it should be at the users home directory

```
touch .smbcredentials
```

then

```
sudo chmod 600 .smbcredentials
```

open the file and add the following information

```
username=<user name needed to access the share>
password=<password needed to access the share>
```

once you have that file in place you will need to change or add the line to your `etc/fstab` at the end after all other lines.

```
//freenas/mast/ /media/plexshare cifs credentials=/home/<username>/.smbcredentials,iocharset=utf8,sec=ntlm 0 0
```

This should allow it to login and mount correctly to the share.

Comment: Thank! I don't know how I missed that, or how it managed to work before!

Comment: Although now, I'm getting an error saying that 'only root can mount //freenas/mast/ on /media/plexshare

Comment: do you really need those settings you are passing .. or can you just use defaults `//freenas/mast/ /media/plexshare cifs defaults 0 0`

Comment: I updated my answer

Comment: Thanks, added an answer detailing what was wrong. Thanks for picking up on my typos too.

Answer (score 1):

Managed to figure it out.

The 'only root can mount //freenas/mast/ on /media/plexshare' issue I was getting was because I was trying to mount using the gui in the file manager, using 'sudo mount -a' or adding users to the fstab options fixed this.

I was then getting a mount error 115. I fixed this simply by replacing 'freenas' with the IP of the machine again.

It has been working fine since.